# NodeJS MySQL error

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

NodeJS code is given below:

```
    app.get('/search', function(req, res){
    var keyword = req.query.q;
    con.query("SELECT Post_Title, Post_Icon, Post_Cont, Post_Author, Post_Date FROM Posts WHERE Post_Title LIKE '" + keyword + "' OR Post_Icon LIKE '" + keyword + "' OR Post_Cont LIKE '" + keyword + "' OR Post_Author LIKE '" + keyword + "' OR Post_Date LIKE '" + keyword + "' ORDER BY Post_Date ASC", function (err, result) {
    if (err){
    console.log("Error on DB SELECT.");
    console.log(err);
    tellSelectError(req, res);
}else{
    console.log("Database selected");
    console.log(result);
    /*res.render('index', {
        info: info,
        result: result
    });*/
    res.json(result);
    }
});
});
```

It send empty json to client browser.

Screenshot is uploaded at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpSDA.jpg

Please help.....
This code is working:
`SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Post_ID = " + keyword` but I want to  use **LIKE** with all coloums of **Posts** excluding **Post_ID**.

console.log(err); logs no error.

Got a news:
When I change the SQL to `SELECT * FROM Posts`, it correctly returning all raws but `SELECT Post_Title, Post_Icon, Post_Cont, Post_Author, Post_Date FROM Posts WHERE Post_Title LIKE '" + keyword + "' OR Post_Icon LIKE '" + keyword + "' OR Post_Cont LIKE '" + keyword + "' OR Post_Author LIKE '" + keyword + "' OR Post_Date LIKE '" + keyword + "' ORDER BY Post_Date ASC` is not working as expected.

Comment: it is just a matter of quotes. Since you are passing a string in the keyword you have to wrap it in quotes

Comment: **keyword** is a NodeJS variable.

Comment: and keyword must be wrapped in quotes so that when you convert it into its value to be parsed in SQL you will not face this issue

Comment: Let me try it...

Comment: try to run the query directly in the db to see if it should return any result (by echoing the sql code produced by the app replacing keyword with its value)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the values you pass to the query in quotes. So the correct syntax for you should be:

```
"SELECT Post_Title, Post_Icon, Post_Cont, Post_Author, Post_Date 
FROM Posts 
WHERE Post_Title LIKE '" + keyword + "' OR Post_Icon LIKE '" + keyword + "' OR Post_Cont LIKE '" + keyword + "' OR Post_Author LIKE '" + keyword + "' OR Post_Date LIKE '" + keyword + "' ORDER BY Post_Date ASC"
```

Note: LIKE is an operator that is used instead of = to search for a value inside a field. = will try to match the full field. To do so LIKE use a wildcard (%) in three different options:

- %keyword the value ends with keyword;
- keyword% the value begins with keyword;
- %keywords% the value contains somewhere the keyword

If you don't use the wildcard it is useless to use LIKE

Comment: Tried it and MySQL returns no error but if it is correct, then it should give me result but it is giving empty json.